# Incorrect configuration settings in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a java maven project which I am running in IntelliJ. The application is running fine. But when I click on the run button I see the following message:
[change configuration settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2UZl.png)
These are the settings for running:
[configuration settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLzvh.png)
[configuration settings 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Acv2H.png)
Here is the project structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nH1CF.png)
The project I am working on is the **eclipse-to...** one
When I click on the **run anyway** it does produce the desired output. But I am somewhat confused why it's giving that error. The red bar appears in the main class.

Things I tried:

- Deleted the configuration and right-click on the file having the main method and run it. Which automatically creates a new configuration.

Comment: Where's your `ConfigurationConvertor` class? I don't have intelliJ handy, but have you checked it doesn't expect a fully qualified class name there?

Comment: If it is a maven project then I would expect a [maven run configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-goals.html).